# Scala function that return another function which can internally hold data

Tags: scala, function

For simplicity, let's say I want to create a function as such:

```
def powerOfTwo(n: Int): Int => Int
```

The output is another function that can be used as such that outputFunction(x) will give me 2^x.

the `n: Int` indicates the range of powers of 2 from 1 to n, that is `{2^1, 2^2, ... 2^n}`. I want these values to be pre-computed such that the resulting function `Int => Int` can be used by a simple lookup to obtain the corresponding element of that Array of powers of 2.

I wonder how can I accomplish that? Should I be making a `Class` which I then use to initialize some internal `var` object, and then pass around a function which will output the corresponding element of that `var` object?

Hope this is clear. Note that power of 2 is just an example. I am interested in how to implement this idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is a little confused but it sounds like you might want to `tabulate` over a collection like `List` or `Vector`.

```
def powerOfTwo(n: Int) = List.tabulate(n)(math.pow(2,_))
```

Now you can get a specified number of precomputed powers of two.

```
val firstTen = powerOfTwo(10)
```

And access the computed values as needed.

```
firstTen(7)  // res0: Double = 128.0
```

If the computations for each value are particularly expensive then you might want to use `Stream.tabulate` because each element will be calculated only as needed but the result is cached (memoized) and can be referenced repeatedly without recalculation.

Something similar can be accomplished with `List.iterate`.

**getting more complex**

Maybe `tabulate` or `iterate` are a little too simple for your needs. Perhaps you want to do quick lookups via two input arguments. Let's say you have a function that performs a complex calculation. It would be nice if, for any given input, the output is calculated only once and it becomes a simple lookup thereafter.

```
// memoize a function of arity 2
def memo[A,B,R](f: (A,B)=>R): ((A,B)=>R) = {
  val cache = new collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[(A,B),R]
  (a:A,b:B) => cache.getOrElseUpdate((a,b),f(a,b))
}
```

Now you can memoize the output of some tough calculations.

```
def toughCalc(b: Boolean, n: Double) = { ....
val toughCalcMemo = memo(toughCalc)
toughCalcMemo(true, 44.3)   // initial calculation
toughCalcMemo(false, 34.4)  // initial calculation
toughCalcMemo(true, 44.3)   // simple lookup
```

Comment: Great. This is in line of the sort of answer I am looking for. So what if the return type is `(Int, Int) => Int`. Then a list or vector wouldn't work. So I guess I need a mechanism to read of the relevant info from some pre-calculated `val` and return the result. I am assuming if I create a `val` and then return a function which reads of a corresponding value according to an input of `(Int, Int)`, that value will not be lost when exiting the function, and I can call the resulting function over and over again ?

Comment: @user1780424, see if my update addresses your questions.

Comment: Yes, more than answered. it gave me a new line of thinking about this concept of `memoization`. Very useful technique to learn. The other answer which talked about Closure from @SpiderPig was also another way of looking at it, which was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A function in scala can remember values. That is also called a "closure".
Therefore you could write e.g.

```
def powerOfTwo(n: Int): Int => Int = {
  val arr = Array.iterate(1,n+1)(_*2)
  i => arr(i)
}
```

However there is a simpler way since Scala can automatically convert many collection types like Array, Vector, List, etc into a function. That means you can write this in one line

```
def powerOfTwo(n: Int): Int => Int = Array.iterate(1,n+1)(_*2)
```

Scala sees that the expected type is `Int => Int` and converts the array accordingly.

Comment: This is great. Closure is the key here then! Just for my understanding, imaging in the above function I created many other temporary `val`s that is required for the calculation, but at end only `arr` is required for the output function `i => arr(i)`. Then can I assume that other non-needed `val`s will not stay in memory, and only the required `val arr` will stay in memory ?

Comment: That's right. Only the stuff that's actually used in the function should stay in memory.